# How to have only 2 RibbonRadioButton?

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon-control

The `RibbonGroup` needs 3 `RibbonRadioButton` for the next (4th) Control to be placed on the next right column. If I have only 2 `RibbonRadioButton` and the next Control is a `TextBox`, the `TextBox` would appear underneath the 2 `RibbonRadioButton`.

How can I have fewer than 3 RibbonRadioButton by itself in one column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Item1 />
    <Item2 />
    <Item3 />
</StackPanel>
```

is what you need. Also you can try to play with width.

Comment: putting RibbonRadioButton or any Ribbon control into a normal WPF Control (e.g. StackPanel) give Ribbon Controls some unpredictable indentation.

Comment: Probably. I have never used Ribbon, and I don't understand, why normal RadioButton cannot be putting to the RibbonGroup? You can change its appearence via `ControlTemplate` to achive your needs. It can be wrong, but it is true logic, nothing more.